Starting a random number sequence using seed in fortran 95
I am writing a fortran 95 code for Brownian dynamics. So I need to insert random numbers at each time-step. To generate the random numbers or 'noise', which needs to be Gaussian white noise, I am calling a subroutine which employs the Box-Muller algorithm as follows -
subroutine box_muller(x)           

implicit none

real,intent(out) :: x
real,parameter :: pi=3.14159265
real :: u1,u2

! Box-Muller
call random_number(u1)
call random_number(u2)
x = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)

end subroutine

I wrongly inserted the seed as follows -
subroutine box_muller_mod(x)           

implicit none

integer :: n
integer,allocatable :: seed(:)

real,intent(out) :: x
real,parameter :: pi=3.14159265
real :: u1,u2

! setting seed   
call random_seed(size=n)   ! n is processor-dependent
allocate(seed(n))
seed = 120000
call random_seed(put=seed) ! effectively initializing the RNG with the seed

! Box-Muller
call random_number(u1)
call random_number(u2)
x = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)

end subroutine

It gave the exact same (random!) number for the whole run.
But I need to use "seed" so that once declared a particular seed in the beginning of the script, it will use a particular sequence of random numbers in the whole run of the code.
If needed I shall be able to change the initial seed and the code will use a different sequence of random numbers this time.
The question is how to do this?

You only need to call random_seed once in your main program.  You are reseeding the PRNG every  time that you call box_muller_mod with the same set of seeds.  ouch.

You only set the seed once in the whole.program, somewhere at the program start. You do not touch the seed anywhere when generating. I am sure we have a duplicate.

@steve What do you mean by 'same set of seeds'? The 'seed' is the name of an array. And I wrote (without knowing the reason why) 'seed = 120000.' I didn't explicitly put anything in the array! Also what is the need of this array size, does it help in choosing the set of PRNs?

@QuestionTheAnswer The array is just a place were you put some bits of starting point data for the generator. Every generator works differently and needs a different number of bits for the starting point. In the standard Fortran generator it is solved by an integer array which can be of various length to be able to store  different amount of data. If the starting point is too trivial, the PRNs generated may be of poor quality, the generators often need some sufficient entropy to start from. Better generators are less prone to this problem.

It is good to read some resources about pseudo random generation. Many are written from the point of view of cybersecurity. You want those written from the point of view of Monte Carlo simulations. There are statistical tests for the quality of pseurandom number streams. With too trivial seeds, the quality may be compromised in some generators.
